# How should I correctly turn on my phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, power-on

This is regularly driving me nuts. Every once in a while, my phone freezes for whatever reason. I press and hold the power button to shut if off. Now comes the part that's giving me trouble.

- If I just press the power button, nothing happens.
- If I press and hold the power button, at some point a picture of a battery appears. It will disappear again after a while (probably because I'm still holding the power button and shutting the phone back off)
- If I press and hold the power button and release it when the battery image appears, the image will stay and indicate that the battery is being loaded.
- If I press and hold the power button for *just the right amount of time*, the Galaxy S2 logo appears and my phone boots.

So, usually I find myself going through this cycle a couple of times until I finally get my phone booted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a power cable plugged in.

In that case you'll have to unplug the cable, turn it on and plug it in as soon as something appears on the screen.

I've had this problem several times when trying to flash the phone while tethered to a computer and forgot to take out the USB cable when rebooting.

Comment: That seems to have been the whole source of the problem. If the phone is not plugged in, the Galaxy S2 logo will appear right away.